# PHP - online lambda functions

Tags: php, expressões-lambda, função-anônima

Caros, tenho um sistema onde o usuário (com permissão de desenvolvimento) pode programar algumas rotinas online, para serem executadas dentro do sistema, sem a necessidade de criar arquivo e chamar via require / include.

Para executar essa função, faço uso do create_function, mas o problema é que, ao criar essa função dentro de um loop por exemplo, ocorre o erro "cannot redeclare class xxxx".

Se for criada a rotina assim: `class aaa{/codigo/}`

E eu fizer um loop para execução:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  $funcao = create_function('', $codigoLidoDoBD);
  $funcao();
}
```

O erro ocorre, pois mesmo tendo nome de função diferente, a classe aaa já foi declarada e registrada em algum lugar :S

**Obs**: Poderia usar o class_exists em cada classe, mas são muitas para alterar...

**Obs2**: As vezes, mesmo declarando o `create_function` fora do *loop* e chamando só a `$funcao()`, o erro ocorre também.

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Quem define o nome da classe é o sistema ou o usuário?

Comment: Isto será um pesadelo de manutenção e segurança.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20394721/why-is-there-a-function-create-function-php

Comment: @PapaCharlie quem define é o próprio usuário.

Comment: @bigown não é não, pq o local onde essas funções e classes são definidas é protegido por grupos de segurança e tals.. o que preciso ainda fazer é determinar quando e como a rotina pode ser executada..

Comment: @DanielOmine não é bem isso, mas obrigado mesmo assim cara!

Comment: @user3123816 vai nessa, o pior é que você não sabe onde está se metendo. pode proteger quanto quiser, pode usar a última inovação em segurança, o que está fazendo é intrinsecamente inseguro e só tem um jeito de não criar enormes problemas de manutenção, se for um fracasso. Estou te alertando porque tenho experiência com este cenário mas acho que você só saberá se fizer e tiver sucesso, se realmente for usado. Veja que várias pessoas concordaram comigo.

Comment: @user3123816, parece que há colisão com os nomes das classes quando você carrega duas ou mais com o mesmo nome. Creio que você tenha que renomear a classe. Pode usar um ID tipo `class UserFulanoDeTal_ID_01{/codigo/}`. Mesmo que haja 2 classes com o mesmo nome, o sistema vai substituir para evitar a colisão.

Comment: @user3123816, postei o link apenas para reforçar o que outros já alertaram sobre o que está usando.. Muitas vezes, encontrar solução para algo "torto" é pior que refazer e desentortar..

Answer (score 2):

A não ser que você crie um parser para antes de realmente executar o código validado você terá problemas.

A inclusão dinâmica de código sem regras ou interfaces proporciona diversos problemas e riscos.

O que você poderia fazer é testar a compatibilidade do código antes de executá-lo com com block `try..catch`

Outra possibilidade é adicionar namespaces dinâmicos assim, mas mesmo se funcionar é uma péssima prática.

Outro ponto é sempre tentar compilar essas inclusões em arquivos e usar esse arquivo ao invés de puxar do banco. Claro, alterando o banco a compilação é executada novamente e caso haja um erro você pode alertar o usuário e não concretizar a compilação,

Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 1):

Minha proposta seria renomear a classe para evitar o carregamento e colisão entre duas ou mais classes com o mesmo nome. Faria um `<textarea>` onde o usuário possa cadastrar todas as funções da classe que deseja.

```
// <textarea>

// functions
public function myname()
{
    echo 'Papa Charlie';
}

public function myage()
{
    echo 'Quase 33 :)';
}
```

Na hora que o usuário submeter o formulário, você cria o nome da classe usando como referência o nome do usuário - ou seu ID - e garante que não haverá colisão com os nomes.

```
$content = 'class UserFulanoDeTal_ID_User
{
    ' . $_GET['myfunctions'] . '
}';
```

Quando for gravar `$content` no seu DB, já estará renomeada. Quando for carregar basta usar o `USER NAME` e o `USER ID` do usuário para invocar a classe e suas funções.